# Flash AS3: automate property assignment to new instance from arguments in constructor

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop, instance

I like finding out about tricky new ways to do things. Let's say you've got a class with a property that gets set to the value of an argument in the constructor, like so:

```
package{
 public class SomeClass{
  private var someProperty:*;
  public function SomeClass(_someProperty:*):void{
   someProperty = _someProperty;
  }
 }
}
```

That's not exactly a hassle. But imagine you've got... I don't know, five properties. Ten properties, maybe. Rather then writing out each individual assignment, line by line, isn't there a way to loop through the constructor's arguments and set the value of each corresponding property on the new instance accordingly? I don't think that the `...rest` or `arguments` objects will work, since they only keep an enumerated list of the arguments, not the argument names - I'm thinking something like this would be better:

```
for(var propertyName:String in argsAsAssocArray){this[propertyName] = argsAsAssocArray[propertyName];}
```

... does something like this exist?

Comment: It should be noted that the reason there's no built in way to do things like this is that (besides a few things like movieclips) objects don't have "names" in any real sense. If you define myFunction(str:String), then you get passed in a reference to a String, and that reference happens to be called "str", but the name "str" is not in any way a property of the String object in question. Hence if you use myFunction(..rest), then the objects that get passed in have no names at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. Here's what I use though:

```
class A {
    private var arg1:Type1;
    private var arg2:Type2;
    private var arg3:Type3;
    private var arg4:Type4;
    private static const PARAMS:Array = "arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4".split(",");
    public function A(arg1:Type1, arg2:Type2, arg3:Type3, arg4:Type4) {
        var i:uint = 0;
        for each (var name:String in PARAMS) this[name] = arguments[i++];
    }
}
```

You may want to check out [Haxe](https://haxe.org/). It has many advantages over AS3 and provides a solution even to this problem, using [rtti](https://haxe.org/manual/cr-rtti.html), which unlike AS3 rtti also contains method parameter names.

Comment: it's just not possible, eh? I was kind of afraid of that. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Using the reflection class [describeType](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/utils/package.html) probably provides the most interesting information regarding the arguments, still unfortunately the property names aren't there either.